# PHP UPDATING Error :

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $serverCon=mysql_connect("localhost","root");
    $serverConnection=mysql_select_db("advweb",$serverCon);     

    $id= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
    $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
    $course = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['course']);

    echo"<form method=POST action=home.php>";
    $query="UPDATE * SET Firstname = '$fname', Lastname = '$lname', Course = '$course' WHERE ID = '$id' ";

    mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_affected_rows()>=1)
    {
        echo "<p>($id) Record Updated<p>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<p>($id) Not Updated<p>";
    }
    echo"
    </form>";
?>
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* SET Firstname = 'Teresa', Lastname = 'Mariana', Course = 'Entrep' WHERE ID = '' at line 1
>   This is the error that shows up.

Any corrections with my syntax?

Comment: you're not using update correctly. RTFM https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html - It's even telling you `to use near '* SET`

Comment: yeah im having trouble with updating syntax..so can you figure out whats my error?

Comment: seeing stars eh @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Dagon chocked full of 'em; it's quite an odyssey.

Comment: waiting for daves oders!

Comment: *deet, deet, deet* - HAL? @Dagon? HAL?

Answer (score 2):

You missed table name and `*` is invalid in update query

```
$query="UPDATE * SET Firstname = '$fname', Lastname = '$lname', Course = '$course' WHERE ID = '$id' ";
```

right one is replace `*` with `tablename`

```
$query="UPDATE tablename SET Firstname = '$fname', Lastname = '$lname', Course = '$course' WHERE ID = '$id' ";
```

Comment: this being the first one submitted.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
   $query = "UPDATE tablename 
            SET Firstname = '$fname', Lastname = '$lname', Course = '$course'
            WHERE ID = '$id' ";
```

You are missing the tablename.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify table name. Set the table name you want to update. Your SQL query Should look like this:

```
$query="UPDATE yourTableName SET Firstname = '$fname', Lastname = '$lname', Course = '$course' WHERE ID = '$id' ";
```